# Regular Expression in Vim that will count 1 or colon

Tags: regex, vim

I am rather new to using vim with regular expressions and I need to count specific entries in a .csv file The entries are in this form:

```
9,1,8-Mar-11,high,A2,mid,500,1000,0.143494345,0.153521446,1121.386992,409.6833333,,
9,2,8-Mar-11,high,A2,mid,500,1000,0.180015537,0.256840072,1190.977918,420.8229933,1,
9,3,8-Mar-11,high,A2,mid,500,1000,0.250273568,0.16378268,1061.417761,419.1692065,,1
```

I need to count the number of 8-Mar-11, A2 conditions which have either `,,` or `,1 (,|1)` or `(,|1),1` on the end of the lines.

here is the regular expression that i use in vim to get some count data:

```
:%s/.*8-Mar-11.*A2.*,,1$//gn
```

What I would like to know is there a way to use either in vim? like:

```
:%s/.*8-Mar-11.*A2.*,1\(,|1\)//gn
```

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're composing a regular expression which is searching for one character or another, alternation using pipes is overkill. Use a character class instead:

```
:%s/.*8-Mar-11.*A2.*,1[,1]//gn
```

Comment: Cool :-). Don't forget to mark one of the answers as 'accepted' (click the outlined check-box next to the score)

Answer (score 2):

VIM regexes are weird and confusing. You have to escape the `|` as `\|` for or

Comment: Vim regexes can indeed be confusing, but you can adjust the level of "magicness": which characters have special meaning. `\v`, for example, lets you use `|` as an OR. See `:help magic` for more information.